# Blender 2.8 Texture coordinates keyframes are not visible in Graph Editor

Tags: animation

Here's the material property I'm animating: Vector Mapping

[image]

No keyframes show up in the graph editor.

[image]

I need to change the interpolation mode to linear, but i can't find the keyframes

Edit:

In version 2.81 the same happens.

[image]

Comment: Is is possible for you to provide the .blend? That would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 11):

I have 2 options for you.

1) You need to select the object AND the node that you want to animate. It should now be visible in your Graph editor.

2) You need to disable the "Only Selected" icon in the Graph Editor (little icon arrow).
See picture
[image]

Comment: Look at the video in the question. The object is selected and no keyframes or curve show

Comment: The Object IS selected but for me it looks like the Diffuse BSDF Node is selected and not the Mapping node.

Comment: Seems to me as the correct answer. Either turn off "Only Selected" button or select the mapping node and the keyframes should be visible in the Graph Editor.

Comment: Exaclty, not do you only need to select the object, but you also need to select the "Mapping" node or you can either turn off "Only Selected".

Comment: The only way to know for sure is for the person who asked the question to say so. They were last seen in July, *last year*. I didn't even use stack exchange then, so it is unlikely they will answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I think I may have found the answer. This is 2.81, but the same thing that solves this issue in 2.79 should be the same. MAKE SURE that the editing content being displayed IS set to f-curve, and also make sure that the visibility is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem earlier with keyframes not showing in the Action Editor of the Dope Sheet. As I remember I switched the Action Editor to the Dope Sheet and then back again.[image: Action Editor]

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift+scroll mouse wheel up to show the keyframes, and shift+scroll down to hide them.

Comment: That doesn't hide them. It just moves them up or down. In this case, the keyframes should be shown on the graph, because the picture shows the origin of the graph, the place they normally appear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the object with the material which has the keyframes you're trying to edit else they won't show either.

Comment: If you watch the video in the question. The object is selected and no keyframes or curve show.